# How can i make a css animation only apply to the image and not its border?

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

I'm using this question format to hopefully make it easier to understand :)

**Problem:**

I want to make an image spin, but I want its border not to spin with it. It will look like an image is spinning in a still white frame.

**Attempted code:**

```
#skin3{
 position: relative;
 top: -71px;
 left: 115px;
 width: 95px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid white;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 cursor: pointer !important;
 margin-bottom: -160px;
 -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

This is the css. Where it says, `border: 2px solid white;` it defines the border. This css spins the image *and* its border.

Html:

```
  <img src="../images/skins/skin3white.png" id="skin3" onclick="changeskin3(); location.href='profile.php'" action="changeskin3.php"/>
```

I don't know why this matters, but it might help :)

**Conclusion:**

I don't want to create a separate border with a div or something, so hopefully this is possible.

I've just started using animations, and i'm still learning. Thanks for helping!

Comment: you've already said you don't want to do the work to make it work, so not sure what we can add. Seems pretty simple to use a separate div with a border.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a separate border with another div? It makes your life soo much easier...

Comment: Why don't you try using a psuedo element ? you wont have to add a div everytime this way. Try it!

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't possible by design. CSS is a box model system meaning each element is given a box to render in. That box has a content, padding, border, margin and outline. The moment you shift that box in any direction (e.g. transform), the whole box moves. Think of it literally like a shipping box as it has contents and a border (the actual cardboard). You can't rotate the contents of that box without rotating the whole box.

Now you could take a proverbial box-cutter to that shipping box and render the whole thing in a canvas and program the whole thing yourself. But honestly, that's overkill.

Instead, it's better to just put a box inside the box and spin the inner box and let the outer box not move. As @garr-godfrey commented, you know the solution, to use a second div.

Comment: And the reason i'm not using a second div is because this image repeats more than 28 times on my page. So it's a lot of work, but i'll get to it!

Comment: Well that's a problem we can solve :-). By "componitizing" your code using open source libraries, you can reuse it. Most of these require some javascript to run but it does help with repetitive code.

Jquery started it with Jquery UI widgets - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954857/how-can-i-design-a-custom-control-in-javascript-possibly-using-jquery
Knockout really made that insanely better later

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html
And now everyone is moving to React JS.

Or you can copy paste.